# How to display records that violate validation in Access insert query?

Tags: validation, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Using Access 2007.  I'm trying to insert records into a table with data validation rules, and I'm getting the error message that Access didn't add "1543 record(s) due to validation rule violations."  Is there any way to make Access display the records that failed validation, so I can figure out which values are breaking my validation rules?  I looked all over Google but couldn't find anything to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could copy the records from the results of the query, then paste into your target table.  Access will create a new table called something like Paste_errors which would contain the records which failed to insert.

Comment: This would probably work for me, except that the target table has an autonumber field and the source table doesn't, so all the values I want to paste are shifted one column to the left.  Instead I made a copy of the target table and inserted to it, then compared the source and the copy.

Comment: So, make a copy of the data file and try it with that.